# Is there a way to resize a drawing in Python turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm new to Python and I'm learning about graphics. I have this drawing I made in Python turtle that I want to make smaller. Is there a way to achieve this without redrawing it? Thanks.

```
import turtle
import math

count = 0
while count < 4:
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(200)
    count = count + 1

turtle.left(135)
turtle.forward(200/math.sqrt(2))
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(200/math.sqrt(2))
turtle.up()
turtle.left(135)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.down()

count = 0
while count < 4:
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(60)
    count = count + 1

turtle.up()
turtle.backward(30)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.down()
turtle.forward(60)

turtle.up()
turtle.backward(30)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.backward(30)
turtle.down()
turtle.forward(60)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perhaps implement a `COEFFICIENT` constant, and mutliply all forward/backward parameters by its value?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple of ways to go about this.  The first, and better, is what @Swifty hints at (+1); make critical dimensions variable parameters that can be changed.  For example:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

HOUSE = 100
WINDOW = 30

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

for _ in range(4):
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(HOUSE)

turtle.left(135)
turtle.forward(HOUSE / 2**0.5)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(HOUSE / 2**0.5)

turtle.left(135)
turtle.forward(HOUSE/2)
turtle.right(90)

turtle.up()
turtle.forward(HOUSE/2)
turtle.down()

for _ in range(4):
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(WINDOW)

turtle.backward(WINDOW/2)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(WINDOW)
turtle.backward(WINDOW/2)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.backward(WINDOW/2)
turtle.forward(WINDOW)

turtle.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

This is a half size version of your house where the original size would be defined with:

```
HOUSE = 200
WINDOW = 60
```

If, however, we've hardcoded too many dimensions to extract into variables, we can always cheat by changing our coordinate system:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()
screen.setworldcoordinates(-width, -height, width, height)  # half size

turtle = Turtle()

for _ in range(4):
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(200)

turtle.left(135)
turtle.forward(200 / 2**0.5)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(200 / 2**0.5)

turtle.left(135)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(90)

turtle.up()
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.down()

for _ in range(4):
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(60)

turtle.backward(30)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.backward(30)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.backward(30)
turtle.forward(60)

turtle.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Yet another half size redrawing of your original drawing.